# How to render a list of components to the DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

I am attempting to create a dynamic form.  I would like to pass in an array of functional components, as children, inside the block of a Modal component and display them using props.children, in the Modal.  I am able to pass one component, by rendering it with a getUserSelector method, however, I have not been able to figure out how to pass a list of components inside the block and display them.  When I try to render the component array with the .map function inside the block (see arraylist snippet included below), the Components do not render and I get the **Warning: "Functions are not valid as a React child**." I have provided both code snippets and a github link for your review (see below).  Can anyone provide any assistance on this?

[Github Link](https://github.com/tlockhart/dynamic-form)

**Single Component Render Code Snippet:**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Modal from "../components/global/templates/Modal";
import Select from "../components/global/inputs/CustomSelect";

function Home(props) {
// default Input components to display on form
  const getUserSelector = () => (
    <Select
      type="selector"
      defaultValues={defaultValues}
      options={emailContacts}
      retrieveSelections={retrieveSelectedContacts}
      handleChange={handleChange}
      values={selectedValues}
    />
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Email Contacts:", emailContacts);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      Click to Show Form
      <div>
        <button type="button" onClick={() => setShowUserModal(true)}>
          Show Form
        </button>
      </div>
      {/*Display Modal*/}
      {showUserModal === true ? (
        // Display Modal
        <Modal
          header="Invite Contacts"
          handleCloseModal={() => setShowUserModal(false)}
          handleSendData={retrieveSelectedContacts}
          handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
        >
          {getUserSelector()}
        </Modal>
      ) : null}
      <div>
        <b>Selected Value: </b>
        {renderEmails()}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Warning**

> react_devtools_backend.js:4026 Warning: Functions are not valid as a
> React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of
>  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function
> rather than return it.
> at div
> at div
> at form
> at Modal (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:289:25)
> at div
> at Home (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:504:92)

**ArrayList Render Code Snippet, which produces error:**

```
function Home(props) {
  const SelectComponent1 = <Select
  type="selector1"
  defaultValues={defaultValues}
  options={emailContacts}
  retrieveSelections={retrieveSelectedContacts}
  handleChange={handleChange}
  values={selectedValues}
/>
  const arrayList = [SelectComponent1, SelectComponent1]
  
  // Render Components
  const renderComponents= () => {
    return arrayList.map((Item, index) => {
      console.log("Item:", Item, "; Index:", index);
      return <div key={index}>{Item}</div>
    });
  };
   


  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Email Contacts:", emailContacts);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      Click to Show Form
      <div>
        <button type="button" onClick={() => setShowUserModal(true)}>
          Show Form
        </button>
      </div>
      {/*Display Modal*/}
      {showUserModal === true ? (
        // Display Modal
        <Modal
          header="Invite Contacts"
          handleCloseModal={handleClose}
          handleSendData={retrieveSelectedContacts}
          handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
        >
          {renderComponents}
        </Modal>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: "When I try to render the component array with the .map function inside the block (sample not included)" - please include this code as well

Comment: @PratikWadekar, I have updated my question, per your request.